# Silent Uninstall Intel Graphics

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-update, intel-graphics

We're currently planning to upgrade over 200 computers from Windows 7 to 10. Unfortunately all these machines don't have compatible Intel Graphic driver version for Windows 10 so the update fails (yes the drivers are fully up-to-date). The only way to bypass it is to uninstall the Intel Graphics driver/software, but I can't find a silent command method for this. We have a central tool that can push commands as an admin but I'm not sure what command to use. Any suggestions?

Note: Reinstalling the drivers back silently isn't a problem as one of our tools can do it.

Comment: Can you explain the steps you perform to uninstall the driver manually?

Comment: Go to control panel find the Intel HD Graphics program and uninstall it.

Comment: Given that, can you find the entry for this component under: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or possibly `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` if so, what is in the `UninstallString` value?

Comment: Went through both paths and unfortuantely had no luck in finding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the devcon utility to remove the display driver silently via the command line. You can get the utility and more information -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon

Once you have the devcon utility you can run --> devcon.exe remove

The Hardware ID for the display driver models that are failing the Windows 10 compatibility check were obtained by opening Device Manager then opening the properties of the display adapter causing the issue, clicking the details tab, within the Property section find the Hardware Ids entry, then copy the first ID listed .